# Using VS Code as external editor in 2D project in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have just started using Unity and c#. I followed a tutorial in which I was using the 3D (Core) template and spent some time setting up VS Code as my external editor and finally got it to work. BUT I'm now trying another tutorial in which I'll be using the 2D (Core) template, and for some reason I'm unable to properly use VS Code for scripting.

I have tried to set VS Code as external editor by going to Browse and opening VS Code from applications. But when I then go to open a script in VS Code I'm met with the error:
"external code editor application path does not exist (/User/name/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app)! Please select a different application"

VS Code does open but I'm not getting any of the intellisense features.

Comment: can you check if the according package is installed in the Unity package manager? If not I'd claim its a bug with the 2D template ... there should be no difference between Unity 3D/2D mode at all regarding IDE (code editor)

Comment: No i don't see the according package. How can I download that?

Comment: in the package manager go to `Unity Registry` and then search for `Visual Studio Code Editor`

Comment: THAT WORKED. Thank you! :) Although for some reason I also had to download Mono (Visual Studio Channel). When trying to get it to work before I had to download the Mono (stable version) or it wouldn't work